# Quarkus integration tests cannot connect

Tags: integration-testing, quarkus

We have a Quarkus 3.6 application that is using the quarkus-amazon-lambda extension. Now we are trying to create integration tests under src/integrationTest/java directory.

When I run the test with  ./gradlew quarkusIntTest I always got Connection refused error. When I run the Quarkus app in dev mode and call the rest endpoint using postman it does work without any errors.

The integration test looks like:

```
  @QuarkusIntegrationTest
public class IntegrationTest {

    @Test
    public void testRetrieveLastMessageEndpoint() {

        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

        APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent request = new APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent().withHttpMethod("GET")
                .withPath("/communiucation/message")
                .withHeaders(headers);

        given()
                .contentType("application/json")
                .accept("application/json")
                .body(request)
                .when()
                .post().then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body("body", containsString("Test ok"));
    }
}
```

When checking the logs I found out that Quarkus is starting

```
java -Dquarkus.log.file.path=/crud-communication-lambda/build/quarkus.log -Dquarkus.log.file.enable=true -Dquarkus.log.category."io.quarkus".level=INFO -Dquarkus-internal.aws-lambda.test-api=localhost:5387 -jar /crud-communication-lambda/build/crud-communication-lambda-local-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar"
```

I tried by maybe using the port given to quarkus-internal.aws-lambda.test-api in restAssured but there we got a 404 error.

Do we something wrong and how can we fix this tests?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue. It seems a temporarily fix for the issue is that you don't use "quarkus-resteasy" extension (doesn't matter if its reactive or not) - as soon it gets added as a dependency in the pom, restAssured returns a 404 when you try testing.